# Integrating Bootstrap Theme into Current Shopify Theme

Tags: bootstrap-4, shopify

I purchased a Bootstrap theme not realizing that I couldn't just upload the theme into Shopify. I have looked for hours on how to integrate it into my Shopify theme, but I can't figure it out. Please help!!!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve as a final result for this site, if I may ask? You seem a bit confused right now in what you are doing. Do you need some help?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can answer your question better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Bootstrap with Shopify Jumpstart theme (no longer in support).

It is, matter of fact, pretty easy to integrate Bootstrap

All you have to do is, get a free theme you like. or one you purchase from Shopify Theme Shop. find `theme.liquid`

Add bootstrap above the `</head>` tag, for example, Bootstrap 5, JQuery.

```
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Adjust the stuff that's on your theme with Bootstrap Classes afterward.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that is possible, sorry EGS.

I am not a big (fan) and user of Spotify unless my client specifically asks for it.

One of the various many good reasons for that is that you can't upload your own HTML code or CSS code easily and seamlessly into Shopify. I'm not sure why they did it this way but it is a total headache for developers. I *think* you might be able to create, MAYBE, HTML or CSS snippets (custom) but even that I'm not sure.

Spotify auto-manages all the code for you.

So I think you should stop looking to "integrate a Boostrap theme" "into a Shopify theme".

You could, among other various options you have now, create a WP site with your BS template, or stick to Shopify.